# What is a good technique for binding a saddle stitch booklet with a hard-ish cover?

Tags: print-design, binding

I'm working on a small saddle stitched booklet. The concept involves a relatively hard-ish, see-through cover. The first time around, I simply folded a sheet of polypropylene and sewed everything together. This way the finished product doesn't stay completely closed/flat.

Is there a way I could execute this that would result in a more elegant product; one that stays closed? I'm thinking something where I sew the pages together, then make and/or attach the harder cover somehow differently. How might I accomplish my goal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more closely related to manufacturing and not design.

Comment: @JohnManly can you show me to the StackExchange (if any) where this question is better suited?

Comment: @JohnManly - As a professional graphic designer (more than a couple of whatever time designations you wish to use) I often have to produce comps, and mock-ups of booklets and brochures. I think it's on topic and within the job description of Graphic Designers. Knowing how to make a case-bound book is a good thing™.

Answer (score 3):

Saddle-stitched booklets have a stitch (usually a metal staple) holding the pages together which also forces the book covers apart into a "fan".

The covers require a spine.

Add an extra bit of material between them to compensate for the thickness of the booklet. It will more nearly resemble a case-bound book. Score the cover at the appropriate space, 1/8," 3/16," or so for up to 8 pages.

This works so well because the two 90° folds on either side of the spine will lie flatter than the one 180° fold stuffed with the pages holding them apart.

Attach the "signature" to the inside-back cover *very* close to the spine with double-sided tape or a bead of cement. You tip-in your booklet "signature."

[image: tip in the signature with double sided tape.]

Then, trim the booklet for a finished look.

Off topic: This also causes a problem referred to as page "creep" where the gutter margin in book signatures must vary to allow for the thickness of folded pages. The centre pages stick out more than the outside pages. This must be taken into account when designing thicker bound documents. It is called "Page Imposition" software or stage of publication.

Comment: Thank you! 'Signature' means 'section', or folded sheets sewn together, right? Also, do I add the tape/cement to what is the 'spine' of the folded sheets? Or to the very last page? (The comparison to 'tipping in' would suggest gluing the 'spine', but since that is extremely thin, I'm not sure how you might attach tape to it?)

Comment: @rachel Yes. Attach the booklet back cover to the inside back cover of the case cover with double-sided tape next to the spine as shown in the sketch.